# C# | Adding password protection for a program

Tags: c#, password-protection

I am currently building a C# app(offline .net), and I wanted to give the users the possibility to have password protection for the use of the program. (store their passwords and then have the program be not accessible with out the right password).
My problem is that I have encounterd almost the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270318/sending-email-without-hard-coding-username-and-password)
Is there any good way of doing this?

Comment: it looks like your answer is already there.

Comment: @askingDude, you should set the best answer of the other question as answer, just do it for the one it helps you the most.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email without hard-coding username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270318/sending-email-without-hard-coding-username-and-password)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in general you should NOT store a password, not in plain text and not encrypted.

What you could do is store in a database the hash of the password user has created at first login then every time he logs in, you hash his input (without saving it anywhere) and compare new hash and saved one, if comparison is ok, password was correct.

this as quick example, you can have a lot of complexity in here if you want to make it very safe ;-)

Comment: With what features in c# would you suggest I do that? app.config?db?(what kind?)

Comment: if you already have a database for your program you can use the database, in a db less program, I would not add it only to store the pwd.