# email sent without putting the password into the code

Tags: java, android, email, passwords, password-protection

Is there anyway to get an email sent without putting the password into the code ?

There are many email api-s that enables to send an email with entering the username and password.

### Example

```
sendEmail("myemail@gmail.com","mypass","subject","msg body");
```

Is there any way around the problem with hard-coding the password in code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email without hard-coding username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270318/sending-email-without-hard-coding-username-and-password)

Comment: use encrypt-and-decrypt  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397213/encrypt-and-decrypt-data-for-android-app-client/8397465#8397465

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options to send email:

1. You include your email and password into the code and in this case
   the application will send emails from this email address.
2. You can ask user to enter his credentials for his email and in this
   case you'll receive a mail from user's address.
3. You can form an intent in your application that will fill neccessary
   fields and call user's email client to send this.

If you want silent way to send email then you should choose 1 or 2. But more secure way is to use the third approach.

Comment: are you sure that there is no other way to do this >?

Comment: I want to clarify: are you asking about the possibilities how to send a email or about the ways how to store credentials not in the code but in other places?

Comment: I need any workaround of hard-coding the password in code, but I guess that is not possible...

Comment: If you do not provide password then you will have no protection for sending emails. I think you can create your own email server without the password protection of your accounts but it is likely that your server will be used for spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user password one time and then store it in your [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). It may be necessary to add a way to change the password later if preferred. Deciding from documentation, the internal storage is even secure, while it is also possible to use additional encryption. This is how most of E-mail clients work.