# Sending data remotely without System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, .net, email, send

I'm currently making a small game in C#, and would like to collect data about my players (It's an opt-in process and requires their full agreement in order to collect some details about them, such as in-game statistics).

The problem with System.Net.Mail is, that I'll have to leave my password inside the C# code (for SMTP authentication) in order to send myself mail with player details.

And as we all know, decompiling .NET code is an extremely easy process, so if I'll just include my email address and password in the code, it's going to be hacked soon after I publish it.

So, is there any good alternative for this in order to remotely send data?

Comment: You can use webservice to send the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email without hard-coding username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270318/sending-email-without-hard-coding-username-and-password)

Comment: Thank you guys, especially Nilesh! Fyodor, while saving the email in an external file and encrypting it sounds like a good idea, the encryption can be cracked with some level of reverse engineering, and encryption without a central server managing the keys can cause trouble if not performed well. Using a webservice to send data absolutely sounds like a great idea, Nilesh. Thanks alot!

Comment: And sorry guys, for some reason I cannot upvote your answers (maybe because of my reputation?).

Comment: @Travier I totally agree with you! Actually I thought that question that I linked contains other ideas, but now I see that they are all about the same in general.